# Error in parsing Json

Tags: iphone, json

When parsing json service , it works fine for first time , but during second time it gave me the error given below

```
-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=11 \"Unexpected end of string\" UserInfo=0x5f57450 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected end of string}"
```

Thanks in advance

Code start parsing:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=%@",tt.text];
```

parsing code ::

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Problem with parsing data" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;
    self.responseData = nil;
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.responseData = nil;
    NSLog(@"%@",[responseString JSONValue]);
    NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"results"];
    [responseString release];
    NSLog(@"count === %d",[latestLoans count]);
        for (int i = 0; i < [latestLoans count]; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@" inside for loop %@",[latestLoans objectAtIndex:i]);
            NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@" trackanme=== %@",[loan objectForKey:@"collectionName"]);
                NSLog(@" artworkurl=== %@",[loan objectForKey:@"artworkUrl60"]);
            [titlearray addObject:[loan objectForKey:@"collectionName"]];
            [imagelink addObject:[loan objectForKey:@"artworkUrl60"]];

        }
    //get latest loan

    NSLog(@"titlearray count == %d",[titlearray count]);
    NSLog(@"imagelink count ===%d",[imagelink count]);
    //fetch the data
    //NSString* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"Kind"];
    //NSNumber* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];
    //float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

        //NSString* country = [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"];

    //set the text to the label
    //label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ from %@ needs another $%.2f, please help",
    //            name,country,outstandingAmount
    //            ];    
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;
    [tbl reloadData];
}


    NSLog(@"url ===%@",urlString);
    // Create NSURL string from formatted string, by calling the Flickr API
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];


    // Setup and start async download
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection release];
    [request release];
```

This is the code of my request, this called every time i press button  :

```
-(IBAction)searchitem:(id)sender
{[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;


[tt resignFirstResponder];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=%@",tt.text];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


}
```

Comment: How and where do you parse the json? An example of the json would also be helpful.

Comment: iam prsing from the  link http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=jack it works fine for the first time , but when i did the same thing second time it gives error.Thanks for your reply

Comment: Can you show use the code with which you start the parsing?

Comment: I edited the question , it shows the code with which i start parsing

Comment: Please post the code which does the parsing ? What library are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: Yes we need the method in which you call the method to parse.

Comment: i edited the question with methods used in parsing ..

Comment: And how does it look to you now you've edited it? Can you read it? I can't!

Comment: @Aman, does look good. Hmmm, can you compare the two different response you've got in responseString? Log it with `NSLog(@"%@",responseString);`

Comment: second time it shows null & it prompts me with the above error

Comment: @Aman then it's not the json/response string itself which is the cause of the problem, there is something wrong with your second request. We need more code, how do you start the request?

Comment: i posted in the question , and thank you for responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was , i did not link my json framework well , i tried new framework available at github and it works fine.

Thanks for all who contributed their ideas and lead me to right direction for solving the problem .

Thank you very much.........

Comment: would you mind giving the link to the new framework and if possible how exactly did you solved the problem? I have in fact the same issue..

Comment: FYI: you can also use [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is part of the standard NS* libraries. This way, you can avoid using external frameworks for this kind of naïve conversions.